# SQL Sort table by number of items in common

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables, user, artist and a join table.
I'd like to find for a particular user, the ordering of the rest of the user table by the number of artists they have in common in the join table, or potentially just the `n` other users who are have the most in common with them.

For example in the table:

```
userID | artistID
-------|----------
   1   |    1
   1   |    2
   2   |    1
   2   |    2
   3   |    1
```

I'd want to get that the ordering for user1 would be (2,3) because user2 shares both artist1 and artist2 with user1, whereas user3 only shares artist1.

Is there a way to get this from SQL?

Thanks

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've provided sample data and desired results.

Comment: . . What threw me off is that you mention three tables, but only one table is needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you always know the user ID you want to check agaist, you can also do the following:

```
SELECT user, count(*) as in_common 
FROM user_artist
WHERE 
  user<>1 AND
  artist IN (SELECT artist FROM user_artist WHERE user=1)
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY in_common DESC;
```

This avoids joining which ***might*** have better performance on a large table. Your example is sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b46cff4/5/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a self-join and aggregation:

```
select ua.userID, count(ua1.artistID) as numInCommonWithUser1
from userartists ua left join
     userartists ua1
     on ua.artistID = ua1.artistID and ua1.userID = 1
group by ua.userID
order by numInCommonWithUser1 desc;
```

Comment: The alias in the count() has transposed letters. I tried to edit it, but an edit has to be at least six characters.

Answer (score 0):

If Suppose you know the user ID you are going to check then this query will complete your requirement and also perform very well.

```
SELECT ua1.user, count(*) as all_Common 
FROM user_artist ua1
WHERE 
(
   Select count(*)
   From user_artist ua2
   Where ua2.user=1
   AND ua2.artist=ua1.artist
)>0
AND ua1.user = 1
GROUP BY ua1.user
ORDER BY ua1.all_Common DESC;
```

Let me know if any question!